# Problem executing a JavaFX by double-clicking

Tags: java, exception, exe, javaexe

I'm developing a program with JavaFX. I made an .exe with launch4j and when I double-click it, it shows a window saying "A Java Exception ocurred". But if I via cmd type java -jar app.exe it works perfectly.

I tried in a Virtual Machine and it works when I double-click it. I have the same JDK and JRE (21 zulu) in my main computer and in the VM.

Comment: I’m surprised `java -jar app.exe` works.  I didn’t think it was possible for a file to be both a valid .jar file and a valid Windows executable.

Comment: maybe starting `app.exe` from the cmd gives better error message

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I kinda fixed it by adding the path of bin directory of the Java Zulu to  the "JAVA_HOME" environment variable. Leave this so someone with the same problem may solve it.